# the proper way to go from staging to production?

Tags: django, angular, express, gunicorn, devops

I am working on an ***Angular2/django(DRF) SPA*** application to pass from staging to production deployment.

I have copied all files of the staging folder to a new folder called production with editing env variables.

Is it a good practice to have similar staging and production environments so that I can safely pass to production after the testing staging?

Answer (score 2):

First, you can check the [deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/) in the django documentation.

Second, it is a good habit to differentiate between staging and production settings.

```
--settings_folder
 |- __init__.py
 |- production.py
 |- staging.py
 |- dev.py
 |- ...
manage.py
```

Thus you may prevent a mess up when changing the settings and possibly each stage has different database and settings.

Thirdly, as you are using Angular you need to manage where the static files go, please check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/).

If you have done all that then you will be fine.